# If I'm active user on many sites, is it possible to remove my account on only one of them?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I'm active user on many sites, and I'd like to delete my account on some of them. Is something like that possible?

It would require to unlink the account first, from what I know, so is it technically possible in the first line?

I wouldn't like to throw away my SO account, as well as orphaning Area51 proposals, if it would be possible to keep them.

Comment: @bummi thanks, I'll risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to http://{some-site}.stackexchange.com/contact (http://stackoverflow.com, http://superuser.com, etc also counts) , choose "I need to delete my user profile". Add some details. Send the form. By doing this you only request deletion on one SE site. Repeat it for as many sites as you want.

Comment: It seems I've messed up things with recent name change. Now I need to wait 30 days. I hope it'll work.

Comment: @ВГД wait, how changing name is related to deleting an account...

Comment: not directly, but I'd just want that my 'deleted' user name contain some manifesto

Comment: @ВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХ It won't, the deleted user name will just be "user155074", regardless of your name :)

Comment: @ВГД Anyway, you can go to a site you didn't change your name directly (if it was changed there as a result of "copying changes to the other SE accounts") and change your name and apply it to all your accounts :)

Comment: well, it doesn't work. I can't change my username on any site now. Are you sure it would be user193042889 or sth similar? I'd like to be sure before I made it.

Comment: @ВГД It does work - just tested. I can't change my username on MSE, cuz I did it yesterday. But I can do it on SO and apply changes to all the accounts - what I just did (changed to "nicae" on all the sites and then reverted back to "nicael"). And yes - your name would be just "user155074" ("user"+your user id there, which is "155074")

Comment: well, I've made a change today and I can't change it (tried on Workplace, here and Travel). But I'll skip it. I just try .

Comment: @ВГД Good luck :) One more thing: be sure to have a valid email in your profile.

Comment: Do you know how long can it take?

Comment: @ВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХ Sorry, I don't. Haven't tried :D